# Given a matrix of integer, create a matrix with 1 or 0 according to which numbers are in the first matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

Not sure the title gives the idea of what I need, so here is a sample:
I have ten (w) combinations (subsets) of 20 (n) numbers taken 4 (k) at time. I need a matrix of dimension w x n with 0/1 in each entry according to the integers in each combination.

```
n = 20; k = 4; w = 10;
A = RandomChoice[Subsets[Range[n], {k}], w]
(* {{4, 5, 9, 19}, {3, 7, 8, 11}, {3, 7, 9, 18}, {1, 3, 10, 17}, {5, 6, 
10, 19}, {3, 7, 13, 20}, {3, 8, 15, 19}, {2, 7, 15, 20}, {11, 14, 
15, 17}, {1, 3, 12, 20}} *)
M = SparseArray[Flatten@Table[Thread[Rule[Thread[{i, A[[i]]}], 1]], {i, w}], {w, n}];
Normal[M]
(* {{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 
 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 
 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 1}}`  *)
```

As you can see I found a way to build M, but I think it is not optimal. Because I have to use a huge A matrix the speed is a critical factor. Any different approach? I'm alo trying Compile but with many difficulties, because I don't know it very well.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very fast :

```
n=20;

A={{4, 5, 9, 19}, {3, 7, 8, 11}, {3, 7, 9, 18}, {1, 3, 10, 17}, {5, 6, 
  10, 19}, {3, 7, 13, 20}, {3, 8, 15, 19}, {2, 7, 15, 20}, {11, 14, 
  15, 17}, {1, 3, 12, 20}};

f = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {Ax, _Integer, 1}},
  Module[{tab},
   tab = Array[0 &, {n}];
   (tab[[#]] = 1) & /@ Ax;
   tab
   ],
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True
  ]

f[n, A]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},  {0, 0,
>   1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},  {0, 0, 1, 0,
>   0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},  {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},  {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
>   0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},  {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},  {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},  {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
>   1, 0, 0, 0},  {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 1}}

Answer (score 5):

This s/b quite quick:

```
IntegerDigits[Total@Transpose@(2^Subtract[n, a]), 2, n]
```

N.b. - I changed `A` to `a` - it's almost always a bad idea to use uppercase initials for you own symbols...

And this is wicked fast:

```
Module[{ca = ConstantArray[0, n w]}, 
 ca[[Flatten[a + Range[0, w n - 1, n]]]] = 1;
 Partition[ca, n]]
```

Of the answers so far, for `n = 20; k = 4; w = 100000;` ( on loungbook, so not testing huge numbers), timings fastest to slowest:

```
{me #2, me #1, andre, Guess who it is, OP, kale #2}
{0.062400, 0.670804, 0.842405, 3.151220, 5.179233, 5.584836}
```

Comment: Curious, with my tests, I obtain a better timing than your best timing

Comment: @andre: Not so curious - as noted, on loungebook. On the other hand, compiling mine and parallelizing would boost it, but I tend to be of the "if it needs to be compiled, I'll do it it C "... and prefer pure mathematica code.

Comment: I'm ashamed. I genuinely hope no one votes mine up. For shame! :) (and my time is 0.56 on my PC vs 5.6 seconds... a loungebook indeed!)

Comment: @ciao I have tried to compile your code, but I didn't succeed (MainEvaluate[...] is called in the compiled code)

Comment: @ciao I mean :  on my machine, the timing of my solution is 0.25 seconds, and the timing of your best solution is 0.26 seconds.

Comment: @andre: I don't "play" on my real machines, so not going to be testing there. In any case, added a minor improvement...

Comment: @andre: but your observation is undoubtedly from greater parallelization on your machine (again, I play on a loungbook...).

Comment: my machine : I7, 4 cores, 8 threads

Answer (score 3):

Untested:

```
SparseArray[Thread[Flatten[Inner[List, Range[w], A, List], 1] -> 1], {w, n}]
```

Comment: for w = 10^6 your solution is about half time faster than mine, that's a good improvement. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I propose:

```
Array[Boole@MemberQ[a[[#1]], #2] &, {w, n}]
```

...Short, but slow.

Well, after that first feeble attempt, I present this faster version...

```
Module[{m = ConstantArray[0, {w, n}]}, 
 Set[m[[##]], 1] & @@@ (Join @@ Inner[List, Range[w], a, List]); m];
```